# Processing JSON output from mysql through php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

Ok so i managed to figure out the php code and it is working and is outputting in the right json format when i view it in browser. Here's the code thanks to help from Starx:

```
<?php
include ("Includes/dbConnect.php");

$_GET['date'];

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM events";
$checkevent = mysqli_query($cxn,$query2) or die("Couldn't execute query!");
$dates = array();
    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($checkevent))
        {
        $eventDate = $row2['eventDate'];
        $eventName = $row2['eventName'];
        $eventHost = $row2['host'];

        $dates[$eventDate] = array('title' => $eventName, 'desc' => $eventHost);

        }
    echo json_encode(array("dates" => $dates));
?>
```

this outputs: 
     {"dates":{"2012-03-16":{"title":"Table Quiz","desc":"MSU"},"2012-03-20":{"title":"Welcome","desc":"Me"}}}

So there has to be a problem with my jquery code. i altered it as to Starx's specifications but still nothing, anyone have any ideas??

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
 {
$("#ical").ical({ 


beforeMonth:function(date)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "getCalendarEvents.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "date="+date,
            async: false, //stop rendering the calender until eventdates is changed.
            success: json.each(function(k,v){
                $.fn.ical.changeEventDates(v); //this function changes the eventdates
            }   
        })
    }   
});
});

</script>
```

Comment: Are all the above show script on the same page?

Comment: no the php is contained seperately in getCalendarEvents.php

Comment: Going out on a limb here and assuming you don't want a multidimensional array that prints as `Array ( [0] => Array ( [date] => $eventDate [title] =>  $eventName [desc] => $eventHost ) )`, but instead, you want `Array ( [date] => $eventDate [title] =>  $eventName [desc] => $eventHost )` - Remove the first $dates = array();

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, But he is looping through while loop. It seems reasonable to us multidimensional. @ OP, check my answer for the update

Comment: You say "but cannot seem to get any results back from the function", but do you know if json is being returned by Ajax or not? If not, it's a server side issue, if yes, then it's a JavaScript/Jquery issue. To find out, use Firefox's Firebug add-on, and check the 'net' tab when you load the page. It will show what, if anything, is being returned by the Ajax call. If you see anything, post it here.

Comment: It's not that it's 'unreasonable' it's that the format he says is required is not how his Array is printing. If you look he said he needs it as `Array ( [key] => value)`, but he has it as `Array([0] => Array ( [key] => value))` -- that's the only reason I mentioned it at all.

Comment: how about if you try to iterate through the json results? using the for in format on javascript itself and then try to run the alert on each key value of the result to see if it has a result or not. like for(var x in json)alert(x); :)

Comment: i checked the net tab in firebug and there doesnt seem to be any call by the Ajax at all, no result no mention of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure there is no futher operation after you echo the encoded json. So use an exit() at the end to confirm this

```
echo json_encode($dates);
exit;
```

#### Updates

On that case, notice that you are using two dimensional array for `$date`. When using `$date[] = array(..)` So you have to access it like

```
json.each(function(k,v) { 
    //Now v will hold the json format 
    $.fn.ical.changeEventDates(v);
});
```

#### Update 2

> {"dates":{"eventDate":{"title": "eventName", "desc": "eventHost"}, "eventDate": {"title": "eventName", "desc": "eventHost"}}}

This format is not quite possible, since every item has same key `eventDate`. You can do it another way. Change up the following in the php

```
echo json_encode(array("dates" => $dates));
exit;
```

Now , `json` in your success function will hold similar format

```
function(json){
   // This will hold the json is this format
   // {"dates":{ 0 :{"title": "eventName", "desc": "eventHost"}, 1 : {"title": "eventName", "desc": "eventHost"}}}
   // Note the numeric indexing
}
```

Comment: thanks but have a any idea how to input data from the database into the array format required by the function??? it needs to be  {"dates":{"eventDate":{"title": "eventName", "desc": "eventHost"}, "eventDate": {"title": "eventName", "desc": "eventHost"}}}

Comment: @rudawg, Yes, thats what the example I showed in my update does

Comment: hey thanks Starx but i need the numeric index to be the eventDate pulled from the database. any idea how to do this??

Comment: @rudawg, json needs to have unique index, like an array. You can make your function to accept `{"title": "eventName", "desc": "eventHost"}` and use the `.each()` method as I showed in my example

Comment: ok may sound silly but do i replace the 'k' and'v' in your code with keys and values from mine??

Comment: @rudawg, No, `k` will hold the key like `0,1,2` and `value` will hold the json value. Just use the code as it is. And pass the v, to the function. It will receive the json value.

Comment: thanks got it working finally, was a problem with my jquery plugin, the json was returning but not showing up initially in my calendar(plugin) i had to go forward then back a month and it showed up. thanks a million :)

Answer (score 0):

your code seems to be fine but the only thing is don't include any other output except for the json string, even the html headers, script and etc. it should only include the json string alone and no other else

Comment: could you tell me what other output i included?? ive been staring at this for  while so my brain is slightly melted

Comment: example if your view the output of this manually on your browser and see the view page source if the result is empty the output should only be "[]" and nothing else should come before or after that not even a white space (" ") it should be clean for your script to read it properly. :)

Comment: so you should not include your javascript on the code producing the json output and should only be using it on the separate part of the site which may be doing the ajax request and not on the script that would echo the json output. :)

Comment: the json is outputting properly so i think it must have something to do with the format of the array i am creating